# Ajax post data attribute to MVC controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in Js. This is my code:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" data-id = "@item.Id" id="accept">Accept</button>

var tempId;
    $('button.accept').click(function () {
        tempId = $(this).attr('data-id')
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TabRequest/AcceptRequest",
            data: { 'id': tempId },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
    })
```

As you can see I'm trying to post `"data-id"` to Action. When I click to to button, does nothing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
$('button#accept')
```

instead of

```
$('button.accept')
```

Since accept is an ID for the button, use `#` as selector and you can use `.` for class selector.

you can see reference for [jQuery seletors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)